# Name or service not known error in EasyWebDav for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, webdav

I'm trying to setup a WebDAV connection using easywebdav in Python. (Using 2.7.8 for now)

```
import csv, easywebdav

webdav=easywebdav.connect('https://sakai.rutgers.edu/dav/restoftheurl,username="",password="")
print webdav.ls()
```

Though when I run this I get the following error message. My guess is that it possibly has something to do with the URL using HTTPS?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/willkara/Development/SakaiStuff/WorkProjects/sakai-manager/file.py", line 4, in <module>
    print webdav.ls()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/easywebdav/client.py", line 176, in ls
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/easywebdav/client.py", line 97, in _send
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='https', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //sakai.rutgers.edu/dav/url:80/. (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it strange that you combine HTTPS protocol and port 80. HTTPS uses port 443.

Though the error message *"Name or service not known"* would rather indicate that the hostname `sakai.rutgers.edu` is not recognized on your system. Try to ping the host.

Comment: I just noticed that it's trying port 80. I'll look into specifying a port. Also, I know that hostname is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you shouldn't have `http://` or `https://` in the beginning of your adress, only the host name. You select protocol with `protocol='https'`. Also, I couln't get it to work if I added the path the url, I had to use it as argument to the operations like `easywebdav.ls('/dav/restoftheurl')` or `easywebdav.cd('/dav/restoftheurl')`.